# Solve the given recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Solve the following recurrence relation $f(n) = 4 - \frac{4}{f(n-1)}$ and $ f(0) = 3$.

The correct solution was provided as:

$f(n) = 2\cdot\frac{n+3}{n+2}$

The $\frac{4}{f(n-1)}$ is particularly what is throwing me off. It seems to break the definition of either a linear homogenous or nonhomogeneous recurrence relation, so the typical methods for solving them are not usable, though that may be a misunderstanding on my part.

I tried to expand a few terms from the relation to see if perhaps a telescoping sum would arise, or some other regular pattern that I could manipulate to no avail.

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a practice in programming, not in Mathematics, where it has other meanings. Use `\cdot` ($\cdot$), `\times` ($\times$) or simple juxtaposition.

Comment: Hint:$\frac 1{f(n)-2}$ is an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: Since you already know the answer, you can prove it by checking that initial condition and recurrence hold for function which is the answer. Or prove by induction.